# Connection to SQL database failed because of an error in initializing provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, tls1.2

I am trying to connect to an internal SQL database which allows TLS 1.2 protocol only.

I am able to log-in to the database using the SQL Server Management studio.

I'd like to connect to that same database using Excel 2013 (for a more graphic report). I have read a lot on Excel having problems with TLS1.2 and the use of ODBC Driver instead since that is the only one which supports tls 1.2.

Sadly when entering the credentials and testing the connection we receive the following error:

> TEST CONNECTION FAILED BECAUSE OF AN ERROR ININITIALIZING PROVIDER. UNSPECIFIED ERROR

Does anybody have experience with using Excel to connect to SQL Server using TLS1.2? Am I doing something wrong? I'm using the Data link: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC drivers. The normal SQL way of adding things doesn't work either but I believe that's because TLS1.2 isn't supported there.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Management Studio will connect on port 1433 by default and use the TDS protocol and really have nothing to do with TLS. So it is not surprising that it works in SSMS.

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2017/09/27/microsoft-excel-tls-sql-server-important-considerations/

> For all NEW workbooks, do not use that menu option. Instead use the
>   "From Data Connection Wizard" and select a compliant driver from the
>   list. A requirement is that you have the SQL Native Client (2008 or
>   2012) or ODBC drivers with appropriate patches per TLS 1.2 support for
>   Microsoft SQL Server below.

So it seems like just using ODBC will not work unless ODBC on your machine has been patched to handle TLS 1.2.

I believe the ODBC update you need is below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

Comment: Hello Thomas,

Thanks for the information. I've updated our ODBC driver and we have now the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 11.0 added to our from data connection wizard (All the other options we have return an error ). This returns a time-out error: Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond.... I've tested to ping to our internal server where the database is on and that succeeds so i'm sure the server can communicate to our database server.

Comment: A quick update, I've installed the https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server sql natice client 2012 also and i believe it's a mix of them both ( since the 2012 alone didn't do the trick for us) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don’t want the analysis services driver. That is to query a SQL Server Analysis cube (SSAS). Can you use the standard SQL Server option in ODBC?

Comment: Hi Thomas, We currently use the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 which seems to work for now. We've installed the odbc update as well as the 2012 client sql driver in order to see this one.

Comment: @Thomas, actually [TDS uses TLS/SSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304492.aspx) for encrypted logins (when enabled) and for encrypted connections (when enabled). So, connecting to a SQL Server using SSMS can involve TLS/SSL.